# Learning Bash Scripting with File Management Practice Question

Tags: bash

I'm trying to learn some Bash Scripting and am having issues with this particular practice problem (Which I will summarize):<

Create three directories (music, images, videos) and sort incoming files based on their extension.

music should contain all '.mp3' and '.flac'
images should contain all '.png' and '.jpg'
videos should contain all '.avi' and '.mov'
All '.log' files should be deleted
Any other files should not be touched and must not be changed

For example, given:

```
bike.png
car.jpg
comedy.mov
error.log
horror.avi
info.txt
interview.mp3
song.flac
tree-small.jpeg
11.10.2017_y
some-directory/
  nested-file.log
```

the script should return:

```
images/
....bike.png
....car.jpg
music/
....interview.mp3
....song.flac
videos/
....comedy.mov
....horror.avi
info.txt
tree-small.jpeg
11.10.2017_y
some-directory/
....nested-file.log
```

My attempts keeps placing the info.txt file into 'images', but not bike.png or car.jpg

```
mkdir music, images, videos
for file in *.mp3; do 
mv $file music
done
for file in *.flac; do 
mv $file music
done
for file in *.png; do 
mv $file images
done
for file in *.jpg; do 
mv $file images
done
for file in *.mov; do 
mv $file videos
done
for file in *.avi; do 
mv $file videos
done
for file in *.log; do 
rm $file 
done
```

I know This is not an effective method, but as I said, I am just learning. This is my first attempt at any scripting done in Bash. I am really confused as to why this script is working for the music and videos directories, but not images. Nothing here is addressing .txt files, but info.txt is still being moved into images.

Comment: but.... why not just `mv *.mp3 *.flac music`. Anyway, check your scripts with shellcheck.net - you did not quote some stuff. And anyway it's all invalid - before `do` you need a `;` or a newline.

Comment: see, `help for`

Comment: Is it an option to just use 'mv *.extension dir' on its own? I know virtually nothing about how Bash would read that. I've only ever read random documentation and watched some tutorials on youtube. Also, yes, I forgot to write the semicolons in this. it has been fixed.

Comment: @Reach4God, `help for` says the semicolon before the `do` like what @KamilCuk said. It can be a newline as well.

Comment: @Reach4God, to answer your question, yes. see `echo mv *.mp3 *.flac music/`

Comment: https://shellcheck.net for validating shell scripts. which was mentioned on the first comment here.

Comment: If you want to understand what your script is doing as it runs, put `set -x` at the beginning, and the shell will print a trace of the commands it's running; if it's still moving info.txt, you should be able to see what step is doing that.

Comment: `for file in *; do case "${file##*.}" in mp3 | flac ) mv "$file" music;; ## other classes; esac` A `case` statement along with a parameter expansion to isolate the extension will make things much easier.

Comment: Also, a decent link to work through is TLDP [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Answer (score 0):

just take away the `,`s on line 1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.